# Drawable as source in Circular Image View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I am using [lopspower/CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) Library to create a Circular Image View like this

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_profile_pic"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/square_shape"
    android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_add_image"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="2"
    app:civ_shadow_color="@color/dark_grey"/>
```

and I have the drawable resources like this

**square_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and

**foreground_add_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="30dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_white_24dp" />
```

the foreground image is being displayed but the android:src="@drawable/square_shape" is not being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

'android:src' tag is for the image source.
You need to use 'android:background' for the square_shape

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
android:id="@+id/nav_header_profile_pic"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:gravity="center"

android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_add_image"
app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_shadow="true"
app:civ_shadow_radius="2"
app:civ_shadow_color="@color/dark_grey"

android:background="@drawable/square_shape"
android:src="@drawable/your_image_file_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As par my knowledge you just need to use this to show image in circular view.

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCircularImage"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/homeLogo"
            app:civ_border="true"
            app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
            app:civ_border_width="8dp"
            app:civ_shadow="true"
            app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"
            app:civ_shadow_radius="10" />
```